# Interpretation of Martin Luther King's essay

Tags: meaning, martin-luther-king

Martin Luther King, Jr. said:

> The function of education is to teach one to think intensively and to think critically. Intelligence plus character – that is the goal of true education.

Can anyone tell me in simple terms what he means?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you give us an explanation of what exactly is confusing you about the passage: that would help us do a better job of helping you.

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate quotes from a single address that King delivered at Morehouse College in 1948.  In context, the address is a critique of education, particularly education that does not improve people morally or mentally. https://projects.seattletimes.com/mlk/words-education.html

"Thinking intensively" is "intelligence".  "Thinking critically", which here seems to mean *assessing what you are told against a moral standard*, is "character."  So the two sentences say the same thing, but in different words, and in a different order.

Together, they express King's belief that the goal of education is not the simple gain or memorization of knowledge, but rather the ability to think and judge.